# Disk Management sees external USB enclosure, but not the SSD inside

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, nvme

I have a 1 Tb M.2 2280 SSD which I have placed in a NVME-to-SATA adaptor, which in turn I have put in an external SATA to USB enclosure. With that configuration I can access the disk without problems. Windows 10 Disk Management describes the disk as “WDC WDS 100T2B0B-00Y SCSI Disk Device”. That description coincides with the disk model number, which is WDS100T2B0B-00YS70.

I place that disk on a new external enclosure, so that I can access it directly as NVME, and it does not work.  Now Windows 10 Disk Management describes the disk as "Realtek RTL9210B-CG USB Device". It shows none of the volumes on the disk. All I can do is change the drive letter and see the properties, which show 0 MB capacity. (The Realtek RTL9210B-CG is a USB bridge that combines a USB device with both a PCI Express (PCIe) controller and a SATA controller).

**I get exactly the same description if I connect the enclosure without a disk inside.**

I do not suspect the new enclosure because I have tried with a similar one (which I returned thinking it was defective) with the same result.

Windows tells me that the appropriate driver for the device is being used.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Unless explicitly mentioned in the enclosure/adapter, only one type of drives is supported, SATA or MVMe. You CAN'T turn a SATA into NVMe by using a different enclosure. This seems to be the problem/misunderstanding here.

Comment: What you're seeing in Device Manager [`Realtek RTL9210B-CG USB Device`] is the controller of the external USB enclosure due the drive not being compatible with the enclosure _(@ChanganAuto's comment explains why)_

Comment: @ChanganAuto: As I specified, the disk type is M.2 2280, so NVME. The first enclosure is for SATA, hence the need to use an NVME-to-SATA adaptor to use that enclosure. I also said that I got the second enclosure to access the disk directly as NVME. Maybe I should have said explicitly that the second enclosure is designed to host NVME disks.

Comment: **"M.2" is just the connector; "2280" is the form factor. Neither has anything to do with SATA/NVMe**. This is what you still don't understand. **"WDC WDS 100T2B0B-00Y" is SATA** (and it has "SATA SSD" printed twice). The 1st enclosure is for SATA so it works; the 2nd is NVME only, regardless of its chipset supporting both, therefore it doesn't work, end of story.

Comment: PS - There's no "NVME-to-SATA" adapter. What you have working is a "M.2 SATA to USB" enclosure/adapter. It's just your wrong assumption that M.2 = NVMe. No, both SATA and NVMe drives fit the M.2 slot.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Now I get it; many thanks. I thought M.2 and NVMe referred to the same thing. I understand now that the adaptor I use in the first enclosure adapts M.2 to SATA **form factors**, not the interfaces. I think it would be useful to others to turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: Unless explicitly mentioned in the enclosure/adapter, only one type of drives is supported, SATA or MVMe.** **You CAN'T turn a SATA drive into a NVMe drive by using a different enclosure.** This seems to be the problem/misunderstanding here because the **WDC WDS 100T2B0B-00Y drive in question is SATA** therefore it requires a SATA adapter.

"[M.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2)" is just the connector, originally intended to replace the old [mSATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Mini-SATA_.28mSATA.29) that although having the same physical dimensions of the even older PCI Express Mini Card isn't electrically compatible with it.

> The M.2 specification has superseded both mSATA and mini-PCIe.

"2280" is the form factor (22mm wide x 80mm long)

Neither has anything to do with SATA/NVMe.

Specific to this question, the first enclosure used was SATA so it worked; the second being NVMe only didn't. The device shown in Device Manager - Realtek RTL9210B-CG USB Device - is the controller of the enclosure. The actual drive inside isn't detect because it isn't compatible.

Comment: RTL9210B-CG controller supports both SATA and NVMe protocols, so SATA drive should be compatible with such enclosure. Actually I have one working fine with M.2 SATA drive. https://www.realtek.com/en/products/connected-media-ics/item/rtl9210b-cg